# Save polygon/area on Google map to local DB and method to check if a point lies in/on/out of polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I am re-phrasing the scenario in an attempt to make it more lucid to understand.

I am working on designing an app that will let the user open up the google map, search for a place/address. Once the location appears on the google map - the user would then be able to create polygon (using mouse clicks to create a polygon, a sort of boundary to form a closed loop/ an area). Once the user has defined/created the polygon I need to get the geometry/cooridnates(lat/long) that defines the polygon and need to save it on my local database eg: oracle.

I have been playing around with the google maps javascript api and it does have a drawing library that lets the user create a circle/rectangle/polygon on the map. I have below queries though:

1. First of all, everything seems to run within the UI layer i.e. javascript code, there's no java code involved. Where would I put my busines logic. Would that be in javascript?
2. Once the user creates the polygon, the app prompts to the user to provide a name to the polygon they just created (eg: my beach house in Myrtle beach). I need to save it on local Data store. For this I am calling the REST web service from the javascript(via ajax ) passing the coordinates of the polygon. I am running into CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) policy in Google chrome. Chrome is not calling the REST web service deployed on my local server.
3. Also,  I would be saving the logged in user name who created a particular polygon, date time, name of the polygon etc.
4. Again, that's something planned for the next phase. As soon as the user log in the application, it will go fetch all the polygon created by this user and will display on the map. This is something sort of reverse engineering to draw a polygon fetching the lat/long from the local database.

Please leave a comment if anything still needs to be specified. I'll make those clarification as soon as I can.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very vague question. There are many google maps resources out there on the internet. I would suggest playing around with some examples first and rephrasing the question with specific code issues that you've encountered.

Comment: user1628461 : Hope this is rather more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can put your business logic anywhere. Based on your description of what you want to accomplish - The search functionality can be done entirely in Javascript using the Google Maps and Places APIs. Once they've selected their polygon the vertices of that polygon, as well as whatever other metadata you've collected can be formatted as JSON and submitted to your REST service for further processing.
2. Your REST service needs to set CORS headers. How you do this depends on which server side stack you're using (Spring? Flask? Express?). Whichever technology you're using there should be ample documentation (and here on stackoverflow) for enabling CORS headers.
3. Again this is less of a Google Maps question and more of a question about user auth/session management in your app server of choice. Ideally your rest service should be token authenticated to prevent data from being maliciously inserted.
4. Your should have a REST endpoint that serves up saved polygon paths for a given user. With this it is easy to reconstruct the polygon and render it on the map.

I take it you've already reviewed the relevant front-end documentation for Google Maps API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

The rest is server side plumbing. The project you described is not rocket science but it does have many moving parts. Getting the architecture right early on is important. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did went through the Google Maps API (maps/drawing/places libraries) and able to construct the polygon and to save the coordinates via REST calls.

The bigger question now is this. Given I have a database that stores the coordinates(lat/lang) for certain positions and this table containes millions such entries.

I need to take one coordinate at a time and check whether the chosen coordinate falls in the polygon or not and I need the solution to be efficient as there will be 1000s of polygons and millions of such coordinates entries in the database table.

Comment: You should be storing your coordinates in a spatial database. e.g. postgis. You mentioned Oracle. I'm not familiar with Oracle products but they must have an equivalent spatial offering. With coordinates stored in a spatial database it should be trivial to do a 'contains' query.

Comment: Even without a spatial database, you can do a bounding box search on indexed latitude and longitude columns to significantly narrow your list of candidates to search. This is outside the scope of this question. You need to do some research and write some code first and come back to ask if you are truly stuck on anything.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is more of a POC that I am performing this time to ascertain how much feasible it is to store and query a particular point(coordinate) for the existence inside/on/outside a given polygon and what would be the right set of tools and technologies for the enterprise solution. I appreciate all your assistance on this.

I was able to get the coordinates from the user (via drawing a polygon with mouse clicks on the map), storing it to the DB(via rest service call, passing the coordinates that define a polygon).

Comment: Reading from the DB for the polygon coordinates and drawing it back on to the map.I was running into some CORS issues(as I was calling the rest service deployed on my local WS from one of the event listener method of Google MAPS api) but for the most part it got sorted out.
Next big thing is to efficiently query the coordinates in a DB (with probably billions record in it)